# how to import java classes with the same names and same namespace (package names) into one maven projec

Tags: java, maven, namespaces, dependencies, pom.xml

Can anyone tell me how to import java classes with the same names and same namespace (package names) into one maven project. I already include those clases in maven project using dependecy tags in pom file. When I want to create new instance of this class i can not define from which project to take class definition. Example:

In project abc i have clas definition:

```
    myclass.FirstClass(){
    Pivate String a;
    // getter and setter for a
    }
```

In project def i have clas definition:

```
    myclass.FirstClass(){
    Pivate String a;
    // getter and setter for a
    }
```

Now I want to use both of those definitions in third project where I should assign value for a atribut from class defined in abd to class defined in def project. I know it sound crazy, but I use it to map object for designig web services.

Thanks, 
Miha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done. Java cannot distinguish two classes with the same qualified name.

You need to rename one of the packages. If at least one of the projects `abc` and `def` is yours, this can be easily done. If not, You probably need something like the Maven shade plugin.